# Wordpress and TimThumb - no thumbnails?

Tags: php, wordpress

Hey there I'm using a theme that has a TimThumb built in and instead the image thumbnails i just see a text link to the post (the image `alt`) because the image is not loading.

I found out that the problem is the URL that comes as the TimThumb `src` which is:

```
    http://mydomain.com/wp-content/themes/cadabrapress/scripts/timthumb.php
    ?src=http://uncleempire.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/starbuck1.jpg&w=75&h=75&zc=1
```

When it doesn't have the http:// and the domain it works just fine (when i change it in firebug):

```
   http://mydomain.com/wp-content/themes/cadabrapress/scripts/timthumb.php
   ?src=/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/starbuck1.jpg&w=75&h=75&zc=1
```

I went to their demo page to see how it works there and they use it like the following:

```
    http://demo.wpzoom.com/cadabrapress/wp-content/themes/cadabrapress/scripts/timthumb.php
?src=/blogs.dir/5/files/2010/10/3932596272_986b6fdb0d.jpg&w=310&h=320&zc=1
```

I have no idea how to do that every image i upload using wordpress media uploader and use as a Featured Image will not have the `http://` and domain in it.

***EDIT:*** I just found out that blogs.dir is for multi site so don't pay attention to this part.

Answer (score 0):

Check your permissions on TimThumbs cache directory, for you it should be located in `/wp-content/themes/cadabrapress/scripts/cache` this directory needs to be writeable. If your on linux run `chmod 777 cache` from the scripts directory.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have filled wrong URL at administration: Settings > Media > Full URL path to files. Delete URL in this field.